# Maxell laser pointer don't work any more in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, pointers

I've been using a USB Maxell laser pointer in Ubuntu 22.04 (installed in a HP Elitebook core i5, 8GB RAM) with no problem until today, when it stopped to work. Now I plug it in in the USB port, turn it on and nothing happens. I reboot my laptop the first time and it was recognize and worked properly, but about 1 hour later when I needed it in another presentation, the problem start again and also rebooting wasn't able to solve the problem. Any help in how to solve this situation will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Febe.

Comment: Since most of us don't have this laser pointer, you have to tell us what it does and what exactly is not working. does the light (laser) stop shining? are there buttons on the pointer that does not work? Which buttons work and which do not work? Have you tried changing the battery or charging the pointer?